# App crashes after adding AuthInterceptor to Apollo client

Tags: android, kotlin, graphql, apollo-client, dagger

my app crashes after adding AuthInterceptor to the Apollo client and I can't seem to figure out why it crashes.

ERROR:

E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                                                                                                         com.apollographql.apollo3.exception.ApolloHttpException: Http request failed with status code `500`                                                                                                  at com.apollographql.apollo3.network.http.HttpNetworkTransport$execute$1.invokeSuspend(HttpNetworkTransport.kt:74)                                                                                                  at com.apollographql.apollo3.network.http.HttpNetworkTransport$execute$1.invoke(Unknown Source:8)                                                                                               at com.apollographql.apollo3.network.http.HttpNetworkTransport$execute$1.invoke(Unknown Source:4)                                                                                           at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SafeFlow.collectSafely(Builders.kt:61)

AppModule:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApolloClient(authorizationInterceptor: AuthorizationInterceptor): ApolloClient {
        return ApolloClient.Builder()
            .serverUrl(serverUrl)
            .okHttpClient(
                OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(authorizationInterceptor)
                    .build()
            )
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAuthorizationInterceptor(
        dataStoreManager: DataStoreManager
    ): AuthorizationInterceptor {
        return AuthorizationInterceptor(dataStoreManager)
    }
}
```

AuthorizationInterceptor:

```
class AuthorizationInterceptor @Inject constructor(
    dataStoreManager: DataStoreManager
) : Interceptor {

    private val tokenFlow: Flow<String> = dataStoreManager.tokenFlow

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request = runBlocking {
            try {
                val token = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    tokenFlow.first()
                }
                Log.i("authorizationInterceptorToken", " $token")

                chain.request().newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $token" ?: "")
                    .build()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("authorizationInterceptor", "Error retrieving token: ${e.message}")
                chain.request() // Return the original request
            }
        }

        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}
```